# SQL Alchemy filtering

Tags: python, filter, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter data by username in Python and sql alchemy  but somehow the filter is not working., i am able to filter by ID and add users., in below code, i just showed the method for filter by username. not sure what wrong i am doing

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 
'datas.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


class User(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

def __init__(self, username, email):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
    # Fields to expose
        fields = ('username', 'email')


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

#endpointtogetuserdetailbyusername
@app.route("/username/<username>",methods=["GET"])
def user_detailbyusername(username):
    user=User.query.filter(User.username=='Tim')
# i tried     user=User.query.filter_by(User.username=='Tim') but no luck
    return user_schema.jsonify(user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please fix your indents

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some method to really get back the records, something like `User.query.filter(User.username=='Tim').all()` or  `User.query.filter(User.username=='Tim').first()`, as can be seen in the examples at http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/#querying-records

Comment: thank you.  the below did the trick . however all() method didn't work.
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()